# Why do two identical files on two different NFS file systems differ 16.7% in number of blocks?

Tags: nfs

I have two identical files, located on two different NFS filesystems.  According to `ls -l` or `du -b`, their sizes are identical, but the difference with `du -k` or `ls -s` is 114072 blocks, or 16.7%.  What may cause this large difference?

```
$ du -k /path/to/nfs1/somefile.dat /path/to/nfs2/somefile.dat
786432  /path/to/nfs1/somefile.dat
672360  /path/to/nfs2/somefile.dat
$ cmp /path/to/nfs1/somefile.dat /path/to/nfs2/somefile.dat
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because of sparse files.
It can happen if the files have blocks which have not been written yet (they remain all 0). The system internally doesn't allocate all space until the whole file has been writen at least once.

It is an optimization that happens automatically on linux by default if the filesystem supports it. Most do.
Just take into account that those files may eventually grow upto their declared size.

For more information and a way to reproduce it with "dd" command (open file, seek far, write just a little):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file

Comment: Is there any way to verify or falsify that this is indeed the correct explanation?

Comment: Wikipedia suggests to play with CP. This will forcibly create a sparse and a non-sparse versions of the file. Not sure if this is enough test: cp --sparse=always /path/to/nfs2/somefile.dat /path/to/nfs2/test1 ; cp --sparse=never /path/to/nfs2/somefile.dat /path/to/nfs2/test2 ;